# Can only retrieve ID from Firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I am using NativeScript and the Firebase plugin so that I can retrieve inputted data by the unique ID. My problem is that I am only getting back the ID and not the data that's inside the ID. This is how the data is structured in Firebase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y70hE.png

The underlined is the ID of each log.

This is the code for when the item is tapped on, taking it to the edit page:

```
viewDetail(id: string){

    this.router.navigate(["./calendar-detail", id],
    {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
    });
}
```

The edit component:

```
 private sub: any;
 public log: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(){
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.firebaseService.getMyLog(this.id).subscribe((log) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          for (let prop in log) {
            //props
            if (prop === "id") {
              this.id = log[prop];
            }
            if (prop === "mood") {
              this.mood = log[prop];
            }
            if (prop === "activity") {
              this.activity = log[prop];
            }
            if (prop === "other") {
              this.other = log[prop];
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

This is the Firebase service that should be getting the log data from the ID:

```
 getMyLog(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {
      observer.next(this._allItems.filter(s => s.id === id)[0]);
    }).share();
  }
```

On the edit html page from this code, it shows the ID but not the "mood":

```
 <Label class="h2" [text]="mood"></Label>
 <Label class="h2" [text]="id"></Label>
```

I'm still getting used to Nativescript and Angular so i'm not too sure if i'm making a silly mistake, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is how I am retrieving the list of "logs":

```
getLogList(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {
      let path = 'Logs';

        let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
             observer.next(results);
          });
        };
        firebase.addValueEventListener(onValueEvent, `/${path}`);
    }).share();
  }
```

Comment: Hello! Please show how you are actually performing the fetch from Firestore.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick reply, I forgot to mention i'm using the realtime database!  I'll edit into the post how i'm getting the list of "logs"

Comment: I think you need to use the addChildEventListener. Right now your search is finding the id level, but you are looking for the child level of the id.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: Would you be able to show me roughly how that would look if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added

Comment: Is it possible for you share a minimal sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj I've tried reproducing it on Stackblitz but i'm having some trouble with the Nativescript Firebase plugin, I try installing it but it keeps saying it doesn't recognise it

Comment: You can not use Stackblitz, {N} can not work within a Browser.

Comment: Do you know what else I can use? Firebase doesn't work in Playground